# How to prevent default image from being deleted when a user gets deleted?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model for users profile images and when I delete a user that has the default image, the default image also gets deleted. I believe this has to do because I set the on_delete=models.CASCADE.

I have tried to put on_delete=PROTECT in the ImageField but it doesn't recognize that attribute.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)
    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300,300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you running? Also, do you have a signal, or code somewhere, to actually perform the deletion of the image itself, or is this all of the code that you are using?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII ImageField is preforming image delete on row delete, it extends  FileField which in this case implements delete method

Comment: @iklinac are you sure? I know traditionally media files don't traditionally get removed from the fs, just the data in the db. That could have changed though. That's why I asked if there was any further code.

Answer (score 0):

The  [`on_delete=models.PROTECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) is argument of `models.ForeignKey` and its purpose is to be used on relations.

What you need in your case is to create your own type of [`ImageField` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/#ImageField) by extending it and  overriding the original class `delete` method with your desired functionality.